# Remove columns or rows with a certain number of cells filled

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to remove columns in a data frame with one (or a certain number) of cells filled. Other similar questions/answers have specified based on filtering out rows with only a unique single specified value, however that is not what I am trying to accomplish.

See the table below and realize that if I am looking to remove columns with three or less cells filled the answer will be the removal of the first three columns. The same question is posed for removing rows with a specific number of columns filled.

Tidy/Dplyr answer is preferred.

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",  "I"), X1= c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), X2 = c(0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 0L,  0L, 0L), X5 = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

  Site X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1    A  0  0  0  0  6
2    B  0  0  0  9  5
3    C  0  0  0  4  2
4    D  0  0  0  1  5
5    E  0  0  0  8  1
6    F  0  0  3  6  5
7    G  0  0  6  0  2
8    H  0 10  0  0  0
9    I  3  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select(where(...))`:

```r
select(df, where(~ sum(!. %in% c(0, NA)) >= 3))
#   Site X4 X5
# 1    A  0  6
# 2    B  9  5
# 3    C  4  2
# 4    D  1  5
# 5    E  8  1
# 6    F  6  5
# 7    G  0  2
# 8    H  0  0
# 9    I  0  0
```

(I'm inferring that `NA` would also not count, but either way if you have `NA`s then `==` doesn't work perfectly anyway.)

Comment: Great answer! How would you do this for rows instead of columns?

Comment: _I_ would use `rowSums` (many similar questions on SO will show that, very similar to zx8754's answer below), others might choose to use `rowwise`/`c_across` (which I don't like as much).

Comment: I changed up this question to include the question about rows as well.  df %>% filter(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))) >=6) # this removes rows based on rowSum. But I don't know how to do it in the context of this question. I know that you said to not use across but I wasn't sure how to work around it.

Comment: `df %>% filter(rowSums(sapply(pick(X1:X5), \(z) !z %in% c(0, NA))) > 0)` @ecology

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace all `0` with `NA` and count them with `purrr::map_df(~ sum(!is.na(.)))` and create a named vector then select each column that has more the `1` entry:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# create a named vector with the count of entries in each column
helper <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(-Site, ~ ifelse(. == 0, NA, .))) %>%
  purrr::map_df(~ sum(!is.na(.))) %>% 
  as_vector()

# select all colums with more the 1 entry 
df_selected<- df %>%
  select(-which(names(.) %in% names(helper)[helper == 1]))

df_selected
```

```
  Site X3 X4 X5
1    A  0  0  6
2    B  0  9  5
3    C  0  4  2
4    D  0  1  5
5    E  0  8  1
6    F  3  6  5
7    G  6  0  2
8    H  0  0  0
9    I  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *colSums* count non zeros, then subset:

```
df[ colSums(df != 0) >= 3 ]
#   Site X4 X5
# 1    A  0  6
# 2    B  9  5
# 3    C  4  2
# 4    D  1  5
# 5    E  8  1
# 6    F  6  5
# 7    G  0  2
# 8    H  0  0
# 9    I  0  0
```